# mouse_event not defining and DllImport not working

Tags: vb6, mouseevent, dllimport

I'm using Visual Basic 6.0 (I know, it's outdated, but what can I say? I'm old-timey like that). I've been trying to get a program to work that makes the mouse click on a predetermined point on the screen after clicking a button (that's not what the whole program will be, but I'm still building it and this is my roadblock)

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
Private Declare Function mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" Alias "mouse_event()" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4

Public Function Mouse_LeftClick()
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim mouse_x As Long
    Dim mouse_y As Long
    X = CLng(1285)
    Y = CLng(134)

    mouse_x = CLng(X * 65535 / Screen.Width)
    mouse_y = CLng(Y * 65535 / Screen.Height)

    i = mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, mouse_x, mouse_y, 0, 0)
    n = Mouse_LeftClick()
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    End
End Sub
```

(This is literally the entire program so far)

To be clear, I'm relatively new at this, so this code was almost entirely taken from another website. But I have since forgotten what that website was, unfortunately.

Now, before I had that first line there (the DllImport), VB6 was telling me that "mouse_event()" didn't exist in user32.dll -- which, to my understanding, it still doesn't.

Once I researched that problem, though, I found the DllImport line which I placed exactly where the internet told me to place it, but now that very same line is producing this error message:

```
Compile error:

Invalid outside procedure
```

...Which only confused me, since I got that from people who actually knew what they were doing (I assumed so, anyways).

Anyways, it's been so long since this program's worked, I can't actually remember the last time I was able to run it without getting some critical error that ends the program, so I turn to StackOverflow to tell me what I've done terribly wrong with my code.

Thank you in advance for anyone who offers their help.

Comment: Remove the parentheses from the alias.

Comment: Whenever I try doing that, for some odd reason, VB6 auto-deletes the Alias "mouse_event" that's left over. I don't know why.

Comment: Sure, because it isn't different from the function name.  So it doesn't *need* an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the DLLImport stuff. It's VB.Net, it's not valid VB6 at all.

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
```

And then, like Hans said, remove the parentheses from the alias in the Declare.